# Any special consideration when adding a foreign key to a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I already have a schema and now want to add the `organization_id` field of Organization table to the `Program` table. 
So I can just add a small `add_column migration` and get done but because this is the `organization_id` field ( the same *_id field that Rails generates ) I wanted to make sure I am not missing any key point here? so just a add_column migration is enough?

Answer (score 0):

After you add the organization id you have to make sure you also put what type of association you want in your models.

for example:

```
Organization model

belongs_to :program

Program Model

has_many :organizations
```

you can learn more here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html